# Explain me, please, what "loop response" is, to help me translate this term into other language

Tags: loop-gain

English in not my native language.

I've tried to find full definition of "loop response" in English, but I failed.

Here is an example of using the term "loop response":

> As a working example of SIMPLIS time domain simulations, the Self Oscillating converter from the What is SIMPLIS? topic is pictured below. This converter oscillates at a frequency dependent on the load current, which prevents the easy derivation of a small signal averaged model. Using the SIMPLIS POP analysis, the steady state behavior is quickly simulated, then the SIMPLIS AC analysis simulates the loop response on the same time domain model. The simulation results for this converter have been compared to hardware measurements. For information on how SIMPLIS simulations compare with real hardware measurements, see the Accuracy of PWL Models topic.

I need to translate this article into other Russian language.

Comment: loop response - отклик контура управления.  Судя по контексту, контур управления здесь закрытый.  Дополнительное объяснение термина [здесь (англ.)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/open-loop-response-of-control-system-for-stability-margin-analysis.html).

Comment: Nick, and, if contol loop is closed, then what's the difference between loop response and step/impulse response?

Comment: I find this tool handy for translating highly specialized terms: https://iate.europa.eu/home

Comment: I suggest you mention your target language. There may be users in this community who are bilingual and can sort out a great translation for you.

Comment: Thanks. The target language is Russian - I have updated the question to mention it. But I now after 6 years I hardly remember the context of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is as follows: Because the term "loop response" was mentioned together with an AC analysis, I think this is nothing else than simulating the ac transfer function of a complete feedback system under open loop conditions - that means: LOOP GAIN.
Such a loop gain analysis is very important to get a picture on the closed-loop behaviour of the system (stability, stability margin, bandwidth, step response...).

EDIT: I think, this interpretation is supported by the fact that oscillations of the closed-loop system were observed.